# Are uploaded photos shared?

Tags: google-plus

If I uploaded a photo to Google Plus, did I post or share it too, or will it ask me first? Is there a way to see what you have shared in Google plus, or what dates you shared or posted?

Comment: How did you upload it? Manually through the website, or automatically from your phone?

Answer (score 3):

Uploaded photos are **not** shared by default.

They are shown to you and then you share them with the circles you want by clicking the "View & Share" button beneath the images when they appear on your timeline or via the "Share" button on the photos page.